# mysql delete the data whose datetime is the nearest to the system time

Tags: php, mysql

In the table of my database:

`id_client` (primary key and auto_increment)

`name_client` (varchar)

`time_insert` (datetime)

for example the datas in the table:

```
---------------------------------------
| id_client  name_client  time_insert
| 1            tintin     2012-08-17 11:04:04
| 2            tata       2012-08-17 11:06:15
| 3            toto       2012-08-17 11:10:05
```

if I want to delete the row whose `time_insert` is the nearest(the closest to) to system time, how can I write the command?

Comment: You should specify what 'nearest' means exactly.

Comment: "closest to the system time" ?

Comment: Sorry my bad, I thought you wanted to delete multiple rows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ORDER BY` AND `LIMIT` is also working for delete statement.

```
DELETE FROM your_table ORDER BY time_insert desc LIMIT 1
```

Comment: In fact there are more than one rows whose time_insert are the same, but I don't know the number. LIMIT 1 it doesn't work

Comment: @marssteve Then add in the other criteria to order the data in the way that you want it so that you only delete the top row.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use the following - which would work if you wanted to backdate a delete if you change the `now()` to the date you want to go back to:

```
delete from tableName order by abs(now()-insert_time) asc limit 1
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using server side time, and have the ability for the user to choose their time zone. 
By using server time you can do like this

```
$curtime=date('Y-m-d\TH:i:s\Z');//get cureent time of surver
$curtime=date('Y-m-d\TH:i:s\Z', round(strtotime($curtime)/60)*60);

$tim1=strtotime("+2 minutes",strtotime($curtime));
$t1=date('Y-m-d\TH:i:s\Z',$tim1);
$tim2=strtotime("-2 minutes",strtotime($curtime));
$t2=date('Y-m-d\TH:i:s\Z',$tim2);

$sql="DELETE FROM tbl_name WHERE time_insert BETWEEN '$t2' AND '$t1'";
```

By using this you can delete the row which time has been near to current time.for example I am using 2 minutes interval.